# XCode 6.3.1 & iOS 8 - assigning a views frame property throws exception

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, frame

I try to set the frame property of a UIView object - worked fine before I upgraded XCode to 6.3.1, now it throws an NSInvalidArgumentException.

This line:

```
contentViewController.view.frame = self.contentContainerView.bounds;
```

now throws this:

```
NSException thrown : *** -[NSOrderedSet initWithOrderedSet:range:copyItems:]: ordered set argument is not an NSOrderedSet
```

I presume it's something to do with code executed as part of the setter for the frame property - anyone else seen this happening ?

Comment: have you tried to set a custom rect to `contentViewController.view.frame`?

Comment: Try this: CGRect frame = self.contentContainerView.bounds; contentViewCOntroller.view.frame = frame;